# single div to trigger toggle

Tags: jquery, html

Hi All I am trying to create a scenario where every time I click 'switch' I toggle between '#one', '#two' and '#three'

I can't figure out how to start the jquery

```
<div class="switch">swicth</div>
<div id="one">1</div>
<div id="two">2</div>
<div id="three">3</div>

<style>
#one, #two, #three{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Huh? What does "toggle" between them mean? Right now they are just all invisible.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you toggle?

Comment: Well, what have to tried? You going to need to start by binding the `click` event on the div `.switch`

Comment: @thatidiotguy: I'm assuming the OP means rotate between them. I.e. make 1 visible, then 2 (hiding 1), then 3 (hiding 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use class selector which will allow you to have any number of such `div`'s.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/m7gSn/2/

```
<div class="switch">swicth</div>
<div id="one" class="myc">1</div>
<div id="two" class="myc">2</div>
<div id="three" class="myc">3</div>  
<style> .myc { display:none; } </style>
```

**JS:**

```
var $myc= $('.myc');
var cp = 0;

$('.switch').click (function () {       
   $myc.hide().eq(cp++).show();       
   if (cp == $myc.length) cp = 0;        
});
```

Comment: yep..makes sense...in fact that would be ideal

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(".switch").toggle(
    function() { hideAll(); $("#one").show(); },
    function() { hideAll(); $("#two").show(); },
    function() { hideAll(); $("#three").show(); }
);

function hideAll() {
    $("#one, #two, #three").hide();
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9XQJG/)

Comment: Rory...perfect...That's what I was looking for. Terrific

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this. After adding a class of `toggle` to the divs you want to rotate between:

```
$(".switch").click(function() {
    var toggle = $(".toggle:visible");
    if (toggle[0]) {
       $(toggle[0]).hide();
       var next = $(toggle[0]).next(".toggle");
       if (next[0]) {
         $(next[0]).show();   
       }
       else {
         $(".toggle").first().show();
       }
    }
    else {
        $(".toggle").first().show();
    }        
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3QuHF/)

Answer (score 0):

A little magic:

```
$('.switch').click(function() {
    var c = $.data(this, 'index', ($(this).data('index') || 1) % 3 + 1);
    $('div').hide().eq(c-2).show();
});
```

Demo: https://tinker.io/0d614